# websocket clients authetication with glassfish in server side

Tags: websocket, glassfish-4

I am using glassfish 4.0 with websocket support add i would like to know how it is possible to check the origin of webcoket clients and autheticate or not their requests. Please help i cant find any solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `origin` header can be spoofed by non-browser clients anytime. So it is of limited use - definitely not for air-tight security.

Comment: i want to know the url from where the handshake is happening not some id for the clients

Comment: Yeah, and that (`origin` == "url from where the handshake is happening") can be faked from non-browser clients.